# Show related posts in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to create an "Also in the blog" iteration of blog posts. I'm happy to just show the latest posts, but can't figure out how I'd go about excluding the current post the user is viewing from this iteration.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
{% for article in blog.articles limit:3 %}

  <div>  
    {{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' | img_tag: article.title }}
    {{ article.excerpt }}
    {{ article.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 20 }}
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're on an article page you'd want something like:

```
    {% assign currentHandle = article.handle %}
    {% assign articlesFound = 0 %}
    {% for addin in blogs[blog.handle].articles %}
      {% unless addin.handle == currentHandle %}
       <div><a href="{{ addin.url }}">{{ addin.title }}</a></div>
       {% assign articlesFound = articlesFound |plus: 1 %}
       {% if articlesFound == 3 %}{% break %}{% endif %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: just fixed the sample. I had typed it here directly rather than testing.

Comment: How to display image as well?
I have tried {{ article | img_url: '1024x1024' | img_tag: article.title }} but then article image and related post images are the same

Comment: For my sample the name of the added article is `addin` so you’d use that in your loop

Answer (score 1):

By using the current page title? And checking if it contains the title of the current blog post.

```
{% for article in blog.articles limit:3 %}
    {% unless page_title contains article.title %}
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In the case that the current article is the second in the loop, this stops the loop after the first article.

Comment: That's strange, the `unless` tag fails if false, or break out from the loop?

Comment: Alright, so == rather than "contains" has got the behaviour working! Weirdly the "limit:3" breaks the code after the first iteration, without it it's fine, but of course shows all the remaining posts. Any idea why?

Comment: Turns out the "contains" is fine too. It's the limit that's breaking the loop.

Comment: Try using  `blog.articles | limit:3` I see this syntax on some docs